# sqlite3 in Python extract entries that correspond to values in tuple

Tags: python, sqlite

I am looking for an sqlite3 command that let's me select entries given by a tuple, let me explain with an example:

Here is my data:

```
my_data = [(1,8),(2,4),(3,5),(4,7),(5,13)]
```

and I am trying to extract entries who's first values are either 1,2 or 4; hence, my desired output is:

```
[(1, 8), (2, 4), (4, 7)]
```

I can achieve that with a code below; however, I think that my code is not optimal:

```
import sqlite3

my_data = [(1,8),(2,4),(3,5),(4,7),(5,13)]

key_indexes = (1,2,4)

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE my_table
          (val_1 INTEGER, val_2 INTEGER)''')

for entry in my_data:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(?,?)''',entry)

conn.commit()

result = []

for ind in key_indexes:
    c.execute('''SELECT* FROM my_table WHERE val_1 = ?''', (ind,))
    temp_res = c.fetchall()

    result.extend(temp_res)
```

I am looking for a code that can replace the for loop at the and with an sqlite3 command.
I want to stick `(1,2,4)` somewhere in this line:

```
c.execute('''SELECT* FROM my_table WHERE val_1 = ?''', (ind,))
```

instead of doing a for loop.
Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the last for-loop you can build up the list of indexes/indices in a string and hit the database just once.
Please note that this is a two-step process, and not vulnerable -- in and of itself -- to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
my_query = '''SELECT val_1, val_2
              FROM   my_table 
              WHERE  val_1 IN ({:s});'''.format(",".join("?"*len(key_indexes)))
# -> 'SELECT val_1, val_2 FROM my_table WHERE val_1 IN (?,?,?);'
c.execute(myquery, ind).fetchall()
```

Additionally:
You didn't directly ask about this, but the first `for` loop and call to `execute()` could be reduced to a single call to `executemany()`.
You should test which of the two options is faster because the DB-API doesn't specify exactly how `executemany()` should be implemented; performance may differ across RDBMSs.

```
c.executemany('''INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?,?);''', my_data)
```

You may read up on `executemany()` here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/
For now, suffice it to say that it takes as the second argument a sequence of parameters.